# How to stop users from being able to editing each other iformation

Tags: php, mysql, session, xampp

The answer is probably really simple, but I've been trying to figure it out and I cant.

I've created a profile page for each "currently" logged in user that has a registered account, but the problem is that anyone can access each other profiles and edit them, using link. For example:

https://localhost/profile.php?username=Msprite can easily access
https://localhost/profile.php?username=Msprite2 by tweaking the link, entering their username.

When accesing a profile, user clicks on a code below getting redirected to their profile using $_SESSION to store their username.

```
`echo '<td><a href="profile.php?username=' . $_SESSION['loggedin'] . '">' . '' . ' ' . $_SESSION['loggedin'] . ' </a></td>';
```

Am I trying to do it the wrong way ? is there another aproach to show settings for each user seperatly. How do I stop a user from accesing information of other users.

```
session_start(); if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
header('Location: admin/index.php');
exit;
```

}

An if statment checks if a user is logged in, is there a way to check if a user is the actuall legit user trying to acces their account information ?

Comment: You simply need to check if the *currently logged in user* is the same as the profile page they’re visiting, and (dis)allow them certain actions based on that.

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: What session variable is `Msprite` stored in?  You don't even need name in URL, just send to `profile.php` and get the info for their username from the session.  And what is an example of code that retrieves and saves info?

Comment: Good point, I thought that you have to store an id (which in my case is the username)in the url in order to retrieve its information. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the POST method to send that information and recognize if the user is the user who tries to access to modify their profile / information.

Then in the validation that you do if the session is set, it is correct, but you must put a second condition that verifies that the session has the value of the user who has access.

I don't know where you have the user information, but assuming you are allowing a particular user it would be something like this:

```
<?
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] == 'Msprite'){
   echo 'access granted';
}else{
   echo 'U dont have perms';
}
?>
```

If you get the data from a database, do the query and then in the condition compare that the value of the session 'username' belongs to the user who is registered in the same database.

Comment: This is what I've been looking for, but, is there a way to automatically store logged in "username" in where 'Msprite' is set manualy ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you show the name `Msprite` in the link and the code for the link uses `$_SESSION['loggedin']` I'll assume that is the loggedin username.

You don't need the username in the link, just use it on `profile.php`:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    // SELECT info1, info2 FROM user_table WHERE username =  $_SESSION['loggedin']
    // Do profile stuff
} else {
    header('Location: admin/index.php');
    exit;
}
```